# iframe height to fit content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I found about 5 methods in the internet by Google searching but none of them seems to work... I see people thanking and saying that it works and I'm just getting frustrated by the fact that it doesn't work for me and I have no idea why.

I have two files, **test.html** which contains the iframe and **hello.html** which has actual content. I want the iframe in test.html to fit it's height according to the content inside hello.html. 
The tutorial that I'm using: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fit-iframe-to-content/
Here are the codes:

**test.html**

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function(){

        var iFrames = $('iframe');

        function iResize() {

            for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
              iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
            }

            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 

               iFrames.load(function(){
                   setTimeout(iResize, 0);
               });

               for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                    iFrames[i].src = '';
                    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
               }

            } else {
               iFrames.load(function() { 
                   this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
               });
            }

        });

</script>
</head>

<iframe src="hello.html" class="iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<html>
```

**hello.html**

```
<html>
<body bgcolor=”#000000″>

<font color=”#ffffff”>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
<p>Child frame.</p>
</font>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Please use jsFidle for this type examples of code. It's better for all who want to help You.

Comment: I manage to get it working, but for some reason .php files don't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it, seems like iframe does problems with margin and position: absolute inside. Thank you for caring WooCaSh!

Comment: Using chrome can also result in problems as it might see this as unsafe iframe manipulation and block it